# Map constructor does not assign String to Object in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Given the following domain class:

```
class Dog {
    Object name // changing the type to String fixes it
}
```

And this unit test:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.*

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([Dog])
class DogSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        Dog dog = new Dog(name:"sparky")
        // dog.name = "sparky" // adding this line also fixes it
        expect:"fix me"
            dog.name == "sparky"
    }
}
```

Running `grails test-app` fails, but if you change the type of `Dog.name` to `String`, it works fine. Debugging brings me to realize that `Dog.name` never gets assigned and is `null`. If I were to set `dog.name` via regular assignment after constructing it as above, the test passes.

This issue does not occur in Groovy Script using the same map constructor assignment.

I want my type to be `Object` as it varies depending on the use case.

Any idea why this is happening? Is it a bug in Grails?

Comment: looks like GORM can't find the serializer for the `Object` data type and fails silently

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10692) bug report on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging and I found out that when a field accepts an Object, grails framework doesn't do databinding on this property.

More specifically, the Dog#name field doesn't belongs to the whitelist of properties when It is declared as Object.

That's why this doesn't work.

If you want to debug, see the

```
grails.web.databinding.DataBindingUtils#getBindingIncludeList(final Object object)
```

If you put a breakpoint there, you will see how grails generates the whitelist of properties.

I think this makes a lot of sense since It's related to security!

See more about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails)

If you wanna bind on an Object field nevertheless, this code may help you:

```
class Dog {
  Object name
  static constraints = {
    name(bindable: true)
  }
}
```